# How do I replace all occurrences of + - with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all occurrences of `+ -` in a string using javascript. How can I do this?
here's the current example http://jsfiddle.net/Tq2z3/ it only removed the first occurrence and not the rest

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: I don't mean to be a jerk, but have you tried a simple google search? Text replacing is one of the most common questions for almost every language out there...

Comment: `str.replace(/\+|-/g,'')`

Comment: @elclanrs That is incorrect; it will remove `+` ***or*** `-`, not `+ -`.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/Tq2z3/2/

Comment: @elclanrs http://jsfiddle.net/Tq2z3/3/

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Works fine for me in Chrome and FF. No `+-` signs after replacement.

Comment: @elclanrs Exactly, no `+` and `-` remain; they should still be there, around the "where are my plus and signs?". Maybe this will demonstrate better: http://jsfiddle.net/Tq2z3/4/

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Why? I think we're reading different questions... The accepted solution outputs the exact same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/Tq2z3/5/

Comment: @DannyBeckettL: Oh I see your point. Pretty sure OP meant `+` OR `-` not literally `+ -` given the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your two replaces to this:

```
var newstr=str.replace(/[+-]/g,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
var newstr = str.replace(/\+ -/g, "");
```

This way, only occurences of `+ -` are replaced; not loose `+` and `-` characters too.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/Tq2z3/5/) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace functionlity in javascript:

```
var sample = "This is a test.";
var newsample = sample.replace("test", "quiz");
```

For replacing all occurrences:

```
var sample = "This is test 1 and test 2";
var newsample = sample.replace(/test/g,"quiz");
```

Regards,